# I2C write block doesn't work

Tags: sensor, range-detector

I am currently working on a SoC sensor. What is there is a process for uploading firmware from the controller to a sensor through I2C. So I am creating a function for read_block and write_block. Read block saves data from I2C to an array buffer, and write block writes a buffer through I2C.

Below is my code for block read and block write.

```
/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Write a Block
 *****************************************************************************/
uint8_t i2c_block_write(uint8_t device, uint8_t address, uint8_t length, uint8_t const *data) {
  uint8_t ret;
  uint8_t i2c_write_data[length+1];

  i2c_write_data[0] = address;

  for (int i = 0; i < length+1; i++) {
    i2c_write_data[i + 1] = data[i];
  }

  ret = nrf_drv_twi_tx(&m_twi, device, i2c_write_data, sizeof(i2c_write_data),false);
  while (nrf_drv_twi_is_busy(&m_twi));
  return ret;
}

/**************************************************************************//**
 * @brief Read a Block
 *****************************************************************************/
uint8_t i2c_block_read(uint8_t device, uint8_t address, uint16_t length, uint8_t *data) {
  uint8_t ret;
  uint8_t register_address[1];

  register_address[0] = address;
  nrf_drv_twi_tx(&m_twi, device, register_address, sizeof(register_address), true);

  while (m_xfer_done == false);
  while (nrf_drv_twi_is_busy(&m_twi));
  ret = nrf_drv_twi_rx(&m_twi, device, data, length);
  while (m_xfer_done == false);
  while (nrf_drv_twi_is_busy(&m_twi));
  return ret;
}
```

When I implement it on main code, I can do read block I2C, but I can't do write block, it is stuck on pull-ed condition (in my condition, it is pulled up).

But when I debug it, it does the process, but after checking the signal response, there is no signal even from controller to sensor. Below is picture from the logic analyzer and in Notepad is a debugging process that I wrote on firmware.

[image]

Does anybody know why my block write is not working?

Comment: What size block are you trying to write, and is your stack large enough to hold that block in `i2c_write_data`?

Comment: What are the sensor and controller part numbers?

Comment: azwawe - Hi, Isn't this question the same as your one [from a few hours ago](/q/641663), but with some additional info included? On this site, we don't like having overlapping or similar questions from the same person, especially not active at the same time. People might see one question without knowing about the other one and hence waste time duplicating replies already done by other people on the other question. If the other question is different, please ASAP edit *both* questions and explain in each one how it's different from the other one, and how answers won't duplicate effort. Thanks.

Comment: Change for (int i = 0; i < length+1; i++) to for (int i = 0; i < length /*+1*/; i++).
You are violating your array boundaries in conjunction with i2c_write_data[i + 1].

Dont know if it solves the problem though.

Comment: Also check if pointers are passed correctly to the library calls. Read the docu. Maybe it needs nrf_drv_twi_tx(&m_twi, device, &i2c_write_data, sizeof(i2c_write_data),false); instead of nrf_drv_twi_tx(&m_twi, device, i2c_write_data, sizeof(i2c_write_data),false);

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent It seems the `nrf_drv_twi_tx` call is correct as it's written. Source: https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v14.0.0%2Fgroup__nrf__drv__twi.html

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Martinsbl/nrf5-mpu-examples/blob/master/nrf_drv_mpu_twi.c) project on GitHub uses `nrf_drv_twi_xfer` to write a multiple registers. Did you take a look at that function?

Comment: @brhans sorry for late response, I was trying to send 2048 bytes from I2C. I am going to upload firmware on SOC.

Comment: Rodo it is CH201.
SamGibson sorry for that, will not do that again.
ElectronicsStudent I already did that but still can't send the buffer. anyway thanks, will check that.
VelVelt thanks, will check that.

Comment: @VelVel Hi thanks for informing me the reference but still doesn't work.